# IF OR AND excel formula

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula where it will look for 8100, 8110, 8120, 8122, 8124, 8251, 8315, 8380 in one column (L) WHILE column (AA) needs to have either 0,1,2,3,4 then it should display "home". This is what I have so far

=IF(OR(L5="8100",L5="8110",L5="8120",L5="8122",L5="8124",L5="8251",L5="8315",L5="8380",AND(OR(AA5="0",AA5="1",AA5="2",AA5="3",AA5="4"),"HOME","NOT HOME"))

I need help implementing col (AA) with 0,1,2,3,4 filter.
so in the end for eg. if column (L) has 8100 AND col (AA) has 0 it should display "home", if it doesn't meet any one of those criteria it should display "not home". Hope my explanation makes sense any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `AND` to encompass both `OR`s, since `AND` is a [standard function that requires two arguments.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/and-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9) A formula like the following should work correctly:
`=IF(AND(OR(L5="8100",L5="8110",L5="8120",L5="8122",L5="8124",L5="8251",L5="8315",L5="8380"),(OR(AA5="0",AA5="1",AA5="2",AA5="3",AA5="4"))),"HOME","NOT HOME")`.

Note that if you're working with numbers that [aren't stored as text](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-numbers-as-text-583160db-936b-4e52-bdff-6f1863518ba4), you should remove the quotes, like so:
`=IF(AND(OR(L5=8100,L5=8110,L5=8120,L5=8122,L5=8124,L5=8251,L5=8315,L5=8380),(OR(AA5=0,AA5=1,AA5=2,AA5=3,AA5=4))),"HOME","NOT HOME")`

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible to achieve with VLOOKUP.
Even better if that's the case look into the MATCH and INDEX combination: https://exceljet.net/articles/index-and-match